# Using rake tasks to interface with heroku

Tags: ruby, rake

I am having issues running a Rake command in my Rails 4 app that uses FileUtils#sh. I am using RVM as my version manager and can't seem to figure out the problem. The error I get is:

```
$ rake db:clone_production:to_local --trace
** Invoke db:clone_production:to_local (first_time)
** Execute db:clone_production:to_local heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -r production
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (18): [heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -r produ...]
/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in `block in create_shell_runner'
... Some more stack trace ...
```

Other Rake tasks work normally such as `$ rake db:migrate` but I can't seem to run shell scripts. The Rake task looks like:

```
# ./lib/tasks/db.rake
namespace :db do
  ...
  namespace :clone_production do
    desc "Clone production database to local database"
    task :to_local do
      sh "heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -r production"
      file = "tmp/db/backup_#{ Time.now.getutc.to_s.gsub(/ /, /_/) }.dump"
      sh "curl -o #{ file } `heroku pgbackups:url -r production`"
      sh "pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d myapp_development #{ file }"
    end
  end
end
```

My PATH looks fine: `/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@myapp/bin:/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/trevor/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/trevor/workspace/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools:/Users/trevor/workspace/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools`

I am using these versions `Rake - 10.1.0`, `Rails - 4.0.0`, and `ruby - 2.0.0-p195`.

```
#./.ruby-version
2.0.0-p195

#./.ruby-gemset
myapp
```

Comment: Is there a `.rvmrc` file in your project folder - if so, what does it contain?

Comment: There is a .ruby-version and it contains 2.0.0-p195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to run the heroku command in a clean environment:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { sh "heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -r production" }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what was going wrong. The Heroku tool belt does not load when you run rake tasks, this means that you must install the Heroku gem in your development group to use Heroku commands in rake tasks. Just a gotchya with Heroku tool belt everyone should know about.